# Exercise about almost sure convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

I have the following problem:

> Let $X_n$, $n \geq 1$ be independent r.v. identically distributed with the probability function:

> $P(X_{i} = k) = P(X_{i} = - k) = \frac{p}{2} q^{k-1}$,  $k = 1,2,...,m$,  $P(X_{i} = m + 1) = P(X_{i} = -m -1) = \frac{q^{m}}{2}$

> where $m>1$, $p\in (0,1)$ and $q = 1-p$. Calculate the almost surely limit of $Z_{n} = \frac{\frac{X_{1}}{X_{2}} + \frac{X_{3}}{X_{4}} +...+ \frac{X_{2n-1}}{X_{2n}}}{X_{1}^{2} + X_{2}^{2} + ... + X_{n}^{2}}$.

The exercise also adds a suggestion that is as follows: Prove that the numerator's limit is $0$ and that the denominator's limit is always greater than $0$.

So far I think I can say that the denominator's limit must be greater than $0$ because for all $x\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, $x^{2} > 0$. I know that $X_{i} \neq 0$ and, therefore, $X_{1}^{2} + X_{2}^{2} + ... + X_{n}^{2} > 0$.

Let me know if there's any mistake in my reasoning and also if you find any way to proceed to find the answer to the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 5):

I'll give you another hint. Note that we may write $$Z_n = \frac{W_n}{Y_n}$$ where $W_n = \frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{X_1}{X_2} + \frac{X_3}{X_4} + \ldots + \frac{X_{2n-1}}{2n} \right)$ and $Y_n = \frac{1}{n}\left( X_1^2 + X_2^2 + \ldots +X_n^2 \right)$. Notice that both $W_n$ and $Y_n$ are the means of iid random variables with finite mean. The strong law of large numbers tells us that $$W_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} E\left[ \frac{X_1}{X_2} \right] $$ and $$Y_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} E[X_1^2]>0$$
Can you compute these expectations and take it from there?

Comment: @mmmmath Does this answer your question? If so, please mark this post accordingly.